# running a php project in wampserver

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a php project made by using CodeIgniter framework. But the problem is when I am trying to run it using wampserver, I am getting the following error.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was     unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

I have made all the database connection successfully.

how will I solve this? My project link is given below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1OEPsG0ILELOUp3bzRFRDhzdnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Take a look into apaches error.log (and your php application log, if there is one...)

Comment: `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.` Look there

Comment: There are some logs in application/errors directory in the project i have provided the link above @Tom Regner

Answer (score 0):

First create a single php page(phpinfo.php) and access it via browser. The script contains:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you can access it via browser : localhost/phpinfo.php
This will output all information about your php configuration.
Search `php.ini` location.

Open the php.ini file and edit to turn on the short tag like:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Comment: how and where will I find the php.ini file ? @reignsly

Comment: @user5404604 did you successfully created and access the phpinfo.php in your browser?

Comment: I think there is a configuration in wamp settings.

Click on your wamp icon then "PHP". Then click on "PHP Settings". There should be an option for "short open tag" which you should enable by clicking on it, it should show a check mark. Your wamp server will automatically restart in a few seconds and then short open tag will be enabled.

Comment: I have tried your project and it works for me. I used xampp not wamp.
If thats the case we should check the apache error log.
Im the sure the cause of the error is there.
Go to your wamp icon > Apache > Apache Error Log.
Paste the content here.